# Can domain name owner redirect form submissions?

Tags: security, dns

Vendor has developed a website, which currently sits within enterprise managed Amazon Web Services (AWS) environment. However the vendor owns the domain name of the website.

The site is an ecommerce platform which allows users to submit personal information for the purchase of insurance products.

Would like to know if it is technically possible for the domain owner to redirect form submissions to a different server (without the enterprise knowing about it). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**It's possible.**

As vendor owns the domain name, it can easily deploy a proxy server and resolve your website domain name to that proxy.

In this way,  the proxy can intercept all user requests, do whatever it wants, before sending the requests to the real server (your server).

Essentially, this is a [Man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack):

> a man-in-the-middle attack (MITM) is an attack where the attacker secretly relays and possibly alters the communication between two parties who believe they are directly communicating with each other.